# Partial derivatives for multivariate functions

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

If $u = u(x, y)$ and $\xi = x + ay, \eta = x + by$, find the values of $a$ and $b$ such that they transform the equation
$$\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}+4\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x \partial y}+3\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial y^2}=0$$
into
$$\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial \xi \partial \eta}=0. $$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: By the chain rule
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial \xi}\frac{\partial \xi}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial \eta}\frac{\partial \eta}{\partial x}=
\frac{\partial u}{\partial \xi}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial \eta}.
$$
Similarly,
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial \xi}\frac{\partial \xi}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial \eta}\frac{\partial \eta}{\partial y}=
a\frac{\partial u}{\partial \xi}+b\frac{\partial u}{\partial \eta}.
$$
Then, taking another derivative,
$$
\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial \xi}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial \eta}\right)=
\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial \xi^2}\frac{\partial \xi}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial\eta\partial \xi}\frac{\partial \eta}{\partial x}+
\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial \xi\partial\eta}\frac{\partial \xi}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial\eta^2}\frac{\partial \eta}{\partial x}
=
\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial \xi^2}+2\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial\eta\partial \xi}+
\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial\eta^2}.
$$
Similarly, you can do this for your other partial derivatives.  Then, choose $a$ and $b$ so that all but the cross term cancels.

To make the last line make more sense, let $\frac{\partial u}{\partial \xi}=v(x,y)$ and $\frac{\partial u}{\partial \eta}=w(x,y)$.  Then
$$
\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial v}{\partial \xi}\frac{\partial \xi}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial v}{\partial \eta}\frac{\partial \eta}{\partial x}=
\frac{\partial v}{\partial \xi}+\frac{\partial v}{\partial \eta}=\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial \xi^2}+\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial\eta\partial\xi}.
$$
The other partial can be computed similarly.

Comment: Can you explain the last row please?

Comment: $\frac{\partial u}{\partial \xi}$ is a function of $x$ and $y$.  If you wanted to, call it $v(x,y)$.  Similarly, $\frac{\partial u}{\partial \eta}$ could be $w(x,y)$.  Then, take the partial derivatives of those functions.

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much! Can you recommend me a source for studying partial derivatives? My courses aren't of much help