# notation in derivative multivariate function - partial and total derivatives in physics

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative, physics

Let $f(x,y)$ is sufficiently smooth for all I write and let $x=x(t)$ and $y=y(t)$. I am curious about a proper notation of derivatives.

Given the limit definition of a partial derivative, I would say:

$$\frac{\partial f(x(t),y(t))}{\partial t}=0$$
and

$$\frac{{\rm d} f(x(t),y(t))}{{\rm d} t}=\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}\frac{{\rm d} x(t)}{{\rm d} t}+\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}\frac{{\rm d} y(t)}{{\rm d} t}$$

If the above is correct notation, why would many physicists (notably it started in thermodynamics) write:

$$\frac{\partial f(x(t),y(t))}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}\frac{{\rm d} x(t)}{{\rm d} t}+\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}\frac{{\rm d} y(t)}{{\rm d} t}$$

what would be the motivation to write the above instead of the total derivative? BTW (I also noticed a similar notation in the answer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2162503/partial-derivatives-for-multivariate-functions) at this forum)